# Tracking elements of another array in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, `$files` with file names and `$imagesFormats` with formats of this images. I want to move every file from `$files` to directory given in `$imageFormats`. Indexes of files and it's formats are same in both arrays. What's the best way to do this - creating another associative array (`$image => $format`) or there is another solution?

Comment: what kind of output do you want? try `array_combine($files, $imagesFormats)` and `array_map(NULL, $files, $imagesFormats)` and look if they are ok.

Comment: I don't want the output, I want to move very image to it's corresponding folder (all formats have their folders).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two array have the same key  you can do in the same foreach  .. eg:

```
  foreach( $files as $key => $value ) {

        yourfunction($value); /// 
        yourfunction($imagesFormats [$key] ) ;
  }
```